# EF code first, model properties types to db data types

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

The EF will create **Nvarchar** data type from a property of type **String**.
Is there a list of how other types are treated by EF and what they will be represented as in the DB created from the model ? Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that mapping table: [SQL-CLR Type Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx). You can also change that default behavior using [`DbType attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype.aspx):

```
[Column(DbType="NVarChar(10) NOT NULL")]
```